# Mule JUnit test for "text/xml"

Tags: java, junit, mule

I have a flow with an HTTP endpoint that expects "text/xml" as the content type.  This flow works correctly when I use something like RESTClient to hit it.

```
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${web.rsc.host}" port="${web.rsc.port}" path="Quote/1_0/submit" doc:name="HTTP" mimeType="text/xml"/>
```

However, I can't get a JUnit test to work.

A stripped down version of the test looks like this:

```
@Test 
public void test5() throws MuleException
{
    MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();

    MuleMessage message = new DefaultMuleMessage( "", muleContext );

    String payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><quote><value>dummy</value></quote>";
    message.setProperty( "http.method", "POST", PropertyScope.OUTBOUND );
    message.setProperty( "http.content-type", "text/xml", PropertyScope.OUTBOUND );
    message.setPayload( payload );

    MuleMessage reply = client.send( "http://localhost:8081/Quote/1_0/submit", message, null, 5000 );

    assertNotNull( reply );
    assertNotNull( reply.getPayload() );
    assertEquals( reply.getPayload(), "200" );
}
```

When this is run, an exception is thrown by Mule on the inbound endpoint: **"Message contained MIME type "text/plain" when "text/xml" was expected."**

What is needed to set the content type on the test message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `HashMap` of properties

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
properties.add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
```

and put it in `client.send`

```
MuleMessage reply = client.send( "http://localhost:8081/Quote/1_0/submit", payload, properties);
```

Comment: That didn't solve the problem. I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: Is there some way to post formatted code in these comments? Or do you want me to put it in as an answer?

Comment: `public void test() throws MuleException { MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient(); MuleMessage message = new DefaultMuleMessage( "", muleContext ); String payload = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><quote><value>dummy</value></quote>"; Map<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<String, Object>(); prop.put( "http.Content-Type", "text/xml" ); prop.put( "http.method", "POST" ); MuleMessage reply = client.send( "http://localhost:8081/Quote/1_0/submit", payload, prop ); }`

Comment: Pasting here is fine for now. [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) is a good alternative

Comment: Thank you.  It appears we'll have to live with manual testing for the moment.

Comment: It's actually `properties.add("Content-Type", "text/xml");`, no `http.` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 message.setProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml", PropertyScope.OUTBOUND );
```